# How to integrate Webflow made front end into .NET Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, webflow

So I want to integrate html index.html, webflow.js, jpgs and some css files that are organised into folders js, css and images. So how to put everything into .NET Core MVC project so it has all the animations and css for html index.html? I use .NET because there should be some logic afterwards with some models etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using .Net Razor Pages and I would follow the .Net docs on templating and laying out views in order to do this, but normally, you will set up a master layout in .net with your webflow html template.

You will place your html tags of header, and body within this, and yield the specific page templates within the body. In your master template, you will also link to your CSS and Javascript files, within an assets folder in your project.

There is a lot that goes into templating, but basically to use webflow, you will copy and paste different parts of your index.html into your master layout as well as into your specific home page template and add an assets folder where you will place and link your css and js.

[Here are some docs from .net core that should help you with setting up your templates.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1)